# Sequelize include wont show all result instead of showing 1 only

Tags: node.js, include, sequelize.js

`   let findNearbyItem = await Outlet.findAll({
where: {
id: outletIds,
},
include: [
{
model: Category,
attributes: ["name"],
where: {
outletId: outletIds,
},
include: {
model: Item,
// attributes: [
//   [Sequelize.fn("max", Sequelize.col("price")), "max"],
//   [Sequelize.fn("min", Sequelize.col("price")), "min"],
// ],
},
},
],
});

```html
   let findNearbyItem = await Outlet.findAll({
      where: {
        id: outletIds,
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Category,
          attributes: ["name"],
          where: {
            outletId: outletIds,
          },
          include: {
            model: Item,
            // attributes: [
            //   [Sequelize.fn("max", Sequelize.col("price")), "max"],
            //   [Sequelize.fn("min", Sequelize.col("price")), "min"],
            // ],
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

`[How to make it shows all the attributes in model:item instead if showing 1 only ? Attached with image[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nedv.png)

Comment: You can't get the min and max in the same row, you would have to use subqueries.

Comment: i am new to sequelize, how do i use subqueries in this case

Comment: @HaydenSooKlcff It would be better if you would write code example as code block inside question, as this image will soon be deleted and then it's impossible to know what was the question about. And when someone have similar problem its hard to know why without half info.